# Creating game like portable module

Tags: javascript, class

I want to create some game. Is it good, that my view on this game has to be like view on the module? It means, anywhere on the other website I want to run my game, I'll just put my module to it.

So, if we imagine "my view" like class, will it look some like this?

```
class Mario {
    // Whole game module
    class Game {
        // Game properties
        class Player {
        }
        class Card {
        }
    }

    class Init {
        // This take care about gui etc.
        class Gui {
             show_cards() {
             }
        }
    }

    start() {
        var init = new Init();
        something to init Gui and run method show_cards();
    }
}

var mario = new Mario();
mario.start();
```

Am I right?

But is this syntax right in JavaScript and is this even possible?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The syntax of your code is in incorrect, you can't nest class declarations like that. It will work if you define the classes one after the other. If this is a good way to do it is a matter of personal preference, thus off topic, hence I've voted to close your question as "primarily opinionated"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the extra awesomesauce of an HTML element you can drop into your page to hold your game code, you could make a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), but I bet you could get by just fine with a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using).

As far as your code structure, this should help you out. It's a `Game` class template that utilizes separate `Player` and `Resource` classes -- and I stuck in a `GameHandler` class at the top for you (which would be like your Mario class.)

Happy coding!

```js
class GameHandler {
  constructor(){
    this.handlerSetup();
    const gameResources = [ // Array of resource objects for setResources method
      {
        type: "card",
        number: 1,
      },
      {
        type: "card",
        number: 2,
        options: { category: "A", description:"special" }
      }
    ];
    this.game = new Game(4, gameResources); // This can go in a loop to allow sequential games
  }
  handlerSetup(){ /* Do setup tasks here */ }
}

class Game {
  constructor(playerCount, resourcesArray){
    this.players = this.setPlayers(playerCount);
    this.resources = this.setResources(resourcesArray);
    this.winnerIfAny = null;
    this.turnNumber = 0;
    this.output("Ready to play");

    // Main loop
    while(this.winnerIfAny === null){
      this.winnerIfAny = this.nextTurn(++this.turnNumber);
    }

    this.output(`Game over -- Player number ${this.winnerIfAny.number} wins`);
  }
  setPlayers(count){
    let i = 0, players = [];
    while(i < count){
      players.push(new Player(i++));
    }
    this.output(`${count} players added`)
    return players;
  }
  setResources(resourcesProvided){
    let resources = [];
    for(let resource of resourcesProvided){
      resources.push(new Resource(resource));
    }
    this.output(`${resources.length} resources added`)
    return resources;
  }
  nextTurn(turnNumber){
    this.output("Taking turn...");
    let winnerFound = null;


    // Turn loop code goes here 
    //   (eg switch to next player, take turn, check for winner

    // This demo game is not very interesting -- it randomly assigns a winner 
    let rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - turnNumber * 2)));
    if (turnNumber > 1 && rand < 4) { winnerFound = this.players[rand]; }    


    if(winnerFound){ return winnerFound; }
    return null;
  }
  output(text){ document.querySelector("#outputDiv").innerHTML += `${text}<br/>`; }
}

class Player {
  constructor(number){
    this.number = number;
    //etc...
  }
}

class Resource {
  constructor(type, number, options){
    this.number = number;
    //etc...
  }
}

new GameHandler();
```

```html
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
```